# Flex-wrap: nowrap is not working correctly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem making the page responsive. The property `flex-wrap: nowrap` is not working properly. Can you please help me to find out where the problem is?

```css
.logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 460px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
    background: black;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: none;
    margin: 0 10px 40px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.contnet {
    background: black;
    min-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    flex-basis: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.bottom-content {
    min-height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: auto;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 430px;
    display: flex;
    flex: auto;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.griditem {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px * 2/3);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-content {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.text {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.img {
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .contnet {
        display: none
    }

    .griditem {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    .img {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }

    .griditem:nth-child(even) {
        margin: 0 0 0 30px;
        order: 2
    }
    .footer{
        display: none
    }

    .griditem:nth-child(odd) {
        margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<hrader class="header">
        <a href="" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <div class="contnet">Content</div>
        <div class="bottom-content">2</div>
    </hrader>
    <main class="main">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="griditem">
                <div class="img">1</div>
                <div class="grid-content">
                    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
                    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio neque magnam amet, praesentium vel illum error autem voluptatibus veniam consequuntur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="griditem">
                <div class="img">2</div>
                <div class="grid-content">
                    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
                    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio neque magnam amet, praesentium vel illum error autem voluptatibus veniam consequuntur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <div class="grid">
            <div class="griditem">
                <div class="grid-content">
                    <div class="img">3</div>
                    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
                    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio neque magnam amet, praesentium vel illum error autem voluptatibus veniam consequuntur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        Footer
    </footer>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9bcpr4L/

Comment: What is "properly"?

Comment: class = "girditem" should be displayed vertically

Comment: `<hrader>`? Are your problems caused by typos?

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan did you check out my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add flex-wrap to `main` and flex-basis to `grid`

```
  .main {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 960px;
      min-width: 430px;
      display: flex;
      flex: auto;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      margin: auto;
      box-sizing: border-box
  }

  .grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px * 2/3);
  }
```

Comment: There were no changed taken place for the third div anyway. The first and the second divs are placed properly.

Answer (score 0):

That's what do you want? I:

1. Moved `.title` and `.text` elements inside `.grid-content` element.
2. Added `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.main` selector.
3. Fixed some typos.

```css
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 460px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logo {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  margin: 0 10px 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  background: black;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom-content {
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: auto;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 430px;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.griditem {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px * 2/3);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-content {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .content {
    display: none
  }
  .main {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .griditem {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .img {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
  .griditem:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    order: 2
  }
  .footer {
    display: none
  }
  .griditem:nth-child(odd) {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Logo</a>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="bottom-content">2</div>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="griditem">
      <div class="img">1</div>
      <div class="grid-content">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio neque magnam amet, praesentium vel illum error autem voluptatibus veniam consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="griditem">
      <div class="img">2</div>
      <div class="grid-content">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio neque magnam amet, praesentium vel illum error autem voluptatibus veniam consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="griditem">
      <div class="img">3</div>
      <div class="grid-content">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio neque magnam amet, praesentium vel illum error autem voluptatibus veniam consequuntur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  Footer
</footer>
```